# Mongoose Results' Default Order

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When executing a `find()` query without any *`sort()`* function, are the returned results in any kind of order? Does this order change between find queries?

I'm trying to understand this default behavior and if it made sense, use it to implement pagination functionality on my API's results.

Comment: When executing a `find()` with no parameters, the database returns objects in forward natural order.